# Linux: re-loading kernel modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm doing some development on a GPU kernel module. It gets compiled only on 'make modules' and not on 'make', so I can say it is a dynamically loaded module that loads on Linux boot. I would like to rapidly recompile and reinstall the module without installing a whole new kernel. Is it ok to simply 'make modules' and then replace the existing .ko file in /lib/modules/... and then reboot?  If not (perhaps it is in use) can I boot into a different kernel, do the replacement, and reboot back in?  Is it possible even to just insmod it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: manetsus, the question is correct, the code is "make modules". Scoob, yes, you can do `make modules`, replace the .ko of your module, unload it with `rmmod module_name` (only if it is not used currently) and reload with `modprobe module_name module_options`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It gets compiled only on 'make modules' and not on 'make', so I can say it is a dynamically loaded module that loads on Linux boot.

You should check where the module is placed. It can be stored only in /lib/modules/...kernel-version../, or in /lib/modules and inside initramfs (initrd). In second case you need regenerate initramfs image after updating ko in /lib/modules.

> I would like to rapidly recompile and reinstall the module without installing a whole new kernel. Is it ok to simply 'make modules' and then replace the existing .ko file in /lib/modules/... and then reboot?

Yes, this is allowed to change .ko file, even when module is loaded. (Loading of the module with `init_module` is done from in-memory copy of .ko ELF file, so used version of module will still use old data).

On reboot you will have all modules and their files unused too.

> Is it possible even to just insmod it?

It is not allowed to do `insmod` of module which is already loaded (compared by name - check EEXIST error in `man finit_module`). You may try to load it with different name, but older module has ownership of hardware and newer module will have no access to PCI/PCIe device.

So, you should unload older module by `rmmod modulename` before inserting newer version. Unloading is possible only for unused modules (`man delete_module`, check usage counter in `lsmod` output) - there should be no other modules depending on your, no processes should use it. After unloading you can do `insmod modulename.ko` or `modprobe modulename.ko`.

Reboot will unload older module and load newer module.

In case of GPU driver you should stop the X.org server and stop system console which uses graphics too (so, you can't switch to text console and reload gpu module interactively; it can be done remotely with ssh or with shell script with unbind/unload/load), check this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/418296/fastest-way-to-reload-graphics-driver-module

> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
> echo 0 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind
> ```